# Oracle SQL to Mimic Nested Window Function

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, analytic-functions, recursive-cte

My actual problem involves a larger row source and more involved math, but this is a small example that still exhibits the challenge faced.  Using Oracle 19c.

Suppose we have a table X with four rows of data as follows.

```
x
-
1
2
3
4
```

Further, suppose we want to derive two columns, a and b, from X such that

- a = x + sum(previous rows of b ordered by x)
- b = a - 1.

Where if there are no previous rows, then the sum is 0.

Therefore, the new table would have rows like the following.

```
x a b
- - -
1 1 0
2 2 1
3 4 3
4 8 7
```

The following is invalid SQL, but provides an example of what is being attempted.

```sql
with
  X AS
  (
    select 1 x from dual
    union all select 2 from dual
    union all select 3 from dual
    union all select 4 from dual
  )
  , A AS
  (
    select
      x
      , x + sum(b) over (order by x range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) AS a
      , a - 1 AS b
    from x
  )
  select * from A
;
```

Perhaps a hierarchical query may help, but not sure on what it is to connect by.

Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a recursive CTE:

```
with X AS (
    select 1 x from dual
    union all select 2 from dual
    union all select 3 from dual
    union all select 4 from dual
  ),
     cte(x, a, b, b_sum) as (
      select x, x as a, x - 1 as b, x - 1 as b_sum
      from x
      where x = 1
      union all
      select x.x, x.x + cte.b_sum, x.x + cte.b_sum - 1, cte.b_sum + (x.x + cte.b_sum - 1)
      from cte join
           x
           on x.x = cte.x + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0a69bc85c4668e6d71dcc4bcb9772b7f) is a db<>fiddle.